# FosUserBundle Facebook Login without flash message

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-login, fosuserbundle

If facebook user is new then it works fine,but if user login with facebook again then flash message of 'user created' occurs.
What i can do to stop flash message on login through facebook.

```
    public function createUserByFacebook($userProfile, $url=null)
{

    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    /*check invites*/
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    /* call register service */
    $registerService = $this->container->get('fly.user.register.service');

    $pwd = $registerService->generateRandomPassword();

    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $user = $em->getRepository('FlyUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('facebookId'=>$facebookId));

    if ($url==null) {
       $url = $this->router->generate('fly_user_profile_change_email');
    }

    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

    if (!$user) {

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setUsername($email);
        $user->setFirstName($firstName);    
        $user->setLastName($lastName);  
        $user->setFacebookId($facebookId); 
        $user->setGender($gender); 
        $user->setBirthday($birthday); 
        $user->setMstatus($mstatus);
        $user->setPlainPassword(rand());
        $userManager->updateUser($user);    
    }


    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

    return $response;
```

But if i remove this

```
$dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

this will redirect to login page

Comment: if you trigger that event and pass it that constant youre going to get that flash message.  Without seeing the rest of your authentication code its hard to advise. But I have a feeling that your approach might be a bit disjointed.

Comment: Do you use [HWIOauthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) also ? When you say *but if user login with facebook again*, you mean whithout unlog first ?

Comment: Nope.After unlog first,If i tried to login with same facebook id,at that i got same flash message which was i got on sign up through facebook.
Yeah,i also used HWIOauthBundle. @Cruz

Comment: @DevDonkey the above code is for UserService.
and i call this service in security controller.

    `public function facebookLoginBackAction() 
    {
        $facebookService = $this->get('fly.user.facebook.service');
        $userInfo = $facebookService->getUserInfo();
        
        $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
        
        return $userService = $this->get('fly.user.service')->createUserByFacebook($userInfo, $url);
    }`

Comment: I dont really understand your login system, but why don't you dispatch the event inside the if (and add the redirection). Outside the if (without user creation) what should be the behavior ?

Comment: why are you calling a method called `createUserByFacebook` when they already exist?  This approach looks messy and confused.  I would test to see if they exist first, then direct them through either a create user method, or an auth method.